# Cloning forms with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

Cloning forms in jQuery, for example to create an RSVP option on a guest list with multiple people, is relatively simple.

```
$(selector).clone().insertAfter(selector:last)
```

It's relatively easy with inputs as well, offering the ability to copy methods or properties by passing `true` to the `clone()` method. To cope with multiple inputs you can append `[]` to the end of your input names:

```
<input type="text" name="email_address[]"/>
```

However this becomes more complicated with `<input>` elements of type `radio`, as you would usually use these to denote a choice:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1"/> <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2"/>
```

Adding the square bracket syntax further confuses things, as there are still multiple values, and some browsers may now allow different selections:

```
<label>Person:</label> <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="1"/> <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="2"/>
<label>Person:</label> <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="1"/> <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="2"/>
```

How can we solve this in a way which allows easy cloning whilst not making radio buttons hard to parse on the back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this can be achieved with a little bit of RegEx fun!

Firstly add a numeric value to your first input element:

```
 <input type="radio" name="choice[0]" value="1"> <input type="radio" name="choice[0]" value="2">
```

Now in your JavaScript

```
$(selector).clone().insertAfter(selector:last)
.find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    var name=$(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('name',name.replace(/([0-9]+)/g,1*(name.match(/([0-9]+)/g))+1));
});
```

Which creates a simple increment in numbers for each element in line with their siblings.

Comment: There was a delay between my question and answer because I forgot to tick the answer box when I asked it - this question was intended to share my own experience of a relatively simple problem, but still something that could be useful for other front end developers.